# Trigger click event on a dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have 2 dropdown lists, the first one goes as follows :

```
<select name="country_id" id="country_id" tabindex="1" onchange="changeLang(this);">

    {section name=jj loop=$jezyki}            

        <option value="{$jezyki[jj].code}" {if $LANG.lang == $jezyki[jj].code} selected {/if}>{$jezyki[jj].name}</option>

    {/section}  
</select>
```

the second one is downloaded from google server, it is a google translate widget. 
What i need is when the user clicks on option from the first dropdown, script should change the value of the widget dropdown list AND trigger the click function to actually translate the page.

```
        function changeLang(someth){
                var nLang = someth.value;
                //$(".goog-te-combo option").val(someth.value);
              //  $(".goog-te-combo").trigger('click');    
        $(".goog-te-combo option[value="+nLang+"]").prop('selected',true).click();
            }
```

the snippet above changes the value. I can see, for example, english selected, but still it does not translate the page

Comment: `{/section}` Valid HTML or you made a typo ?

Comment: try with `.change()` instead.

Comment: @GaurangTandon it's a part of php code to loop the list of available languages

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle so we could check what you are trying to do, not sure i understand it

Comment: @A.Wolff i am talking about google translate widget, here's the link: translate.google.com/translate_tools

Comment: @A.Wolff hmm, seems like jsfiddle can't load the google translate widget

Comment: Ya ok but isn't it using an iframe? Have you any link i can see this widget online?

Comment: @A.Wolff http://www.turbo.technetium.com.pl/ here it is, i've stylized it, so it doesn't look like a normal one, look at the top right corner

Comment: @A.Wolff as for this version, i am trying to make it work on localhost before i can upload it on a server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to dispatch onchange event:

```
function changeLang(someth) {
    var nLang = someth.value,
        evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
    $('.goog-te-combo').val(nLang)[0].dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
var $el = $(".goog-te-combo option[value=" + nLang + "]");
$el.prop('selected',true);
$el.trigger("click");
```

More on [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Comment: and what is wrong with OP's try? this does same thing.

Comment: @jai its trigger('click').

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing other day.
Simple solution since you are using jQuery:

```
<select id="selectId"></select>

<script type="text/javascript">

/*for an action event upon a change i did this*/
$('#first-dropdown-id').change(function(){
     //your code

     /*nesting the click trigger function for it to get triggered*/
     $('#widget-dropwdown-id').trigger( "click" ); 
     }

});


</script>
```

Comment: first - i need to change something after a change of dropdown, not after clicking on it  
  second - have you read my question at all ?

Comment: @user3334216 - I read the question again. 
try the above approach now. I am trying my best to help you here.